# Rails 3 - Ajax Put request gives 404, yet it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am updating a task status from my deal overview page where i am displaying my list of tasks for that deal

It works, the task gets updated. However, i get a nasty 404 error.

Any ideas?

js/coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
    $(".complete_task").live "click", ->
    task_id = $(this).attr("value")
    alert "checkbox clicked" + task_id
    $('ul#tasks').sortable "refresh"
    $.ajax 
      url: "tasks/" + task_id
      data: "&task[is_completed]=2"
      type: "PUT"
      success: ->
        $(this).addClass "done"
```

My firebug output

http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/7899/screenshot20110901at102.png

I'm open to suggestions if this is not the "right way" to do it. Though the requirement is that it must be done with ajax.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Requested Information

Routing Error

```
<h1>Routing Error</h1>
```

```
No route matches {:controller=>"tasks", :action=>"show", :id=>#<Deal id: 1, title: "4919 Torrey Pines Run", user_id: nil, created_at: "2011-09-02 00:08:24", updated_at: "2011-09-02 00:08:24", account_id: 1>, :format=>#<Task id: 39, title: "new tdsfsdf", position: 25, user_id: nil, deal_id: 1, created_at: "2011-09-02 02:49:09", updated_at: "2011-09-02 02:50:31", is_completed: 2, user_who_completed: nil>}
```

routes

```
  resources :accounts do
resources :users
resources :deals do
  post :sort, on: :member
  resources :tasks do
    post :sort, on: :collection 
  end
end
```

end

respond_to block

```
def update
 respond_to do |format|
   if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
     format.html { redirect_to([@task.deal, @task], :notice => 'Task was successfully updated.') }
     format.xml  { head :ok }
     format.js   { render :nothing => true } 

   else
     format.html { render :action => "edit" }
     format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
     format.js   { render :nothing => true } 

   end
 end
```

end

rake/grep

```
MacBook-Pro-2:accountable jbeasley6651$ rake routes | grep tasks
 sort_account_deal_tasks POST   /accounts/:account_id/deals/:deal_id/tasks/sort(.:format)     {:action=>"sort", :controller=>"tasks"}
  account_deal_tasks GET    /accounts/:account_id/deals/:deal_id/tasks(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tasks"}
                     POST   /accounts/:account_id/deals/:deal_id/tasks(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"tasks"}
   new_account_deal_task GET    /accounts/:account_id/deals/:deal_id/tasks/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tasks"}
  edit_account_deal_task GET    /accounts/:account_id/deals/:deal_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"tasks"}
       account_deal_task GET    /accounts/:account_id/deals/:deal_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tasks"}
                     PUT    /accounts/:account_id/deals/:deal_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"tasks"}
                     DELETE /accounts/:account_id/deals/:deal_id/tasks/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"tasks"}
```

Comment: Can you show your `accounts/deals/tasks routes`? Also, can you show your controller response (or the respond_to block at least) for the `Tasks` controller?

Comment: Added the information you requested

Comment: Can you also `rake routes | grep tasks` and show the output?

Comment: added the information you requested (thanks again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the account to your redirect, e.g.

```
# adding it as @account, change to however you're referencing it.
# params[:account_id] should also work.
format.html { redirect_to([@account, @task.deal, @task], ...) }
```

Also, as noted in the comments, your Ajax request isn't asking for javascript, but rather HTML.  You'd need to do what Kristian PD says and put `dataType: script` to the options to specify JS, e.g.

```
$.ajax 
  url: "tasks/" + task_id
  data: "&task[is_completed]=2"
  type: "PUT"
  dataType: "script"
  success: ->
    $(this).addClass "done"
```

Comment: I agree this is a problem too, but I believe the JS issue is related to it not picking the right response format.

Comment: I disagree.  You say it is updating, and the array you're passing to `redirect_to` don't correspond to a route.  I'd bet the farm on the routing error arising from that redirect line.  You're requesting HTML, not JS.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe i didn't notice this... Thank you so much. Until yesterday there were no "accounts" and i just had deals and tasks, I thought I had updated all the routes once i put everything under accounts, but apparently i missed one. Thanks again!

Comment: joel, can you put a debugger inside the JS response? Did you try the dataType fix? If not, putting `url: "tasks/" + task_id + ".js"` should get you to the right response format. 

@numbers is right in that it will get rid of the 404 but I don't think it should be hitting the html response block anyway on an ajax request.  It should just be rendering :nothing.

Comment: Kristian, thanks for the help, without you asking for the additional infor numbers wouldn't have had the info to help me. Numbers - My question now is why does my format.html response have any effect on my js call?

Comment: You need to add `dataType: script` to the options for JS.  You're making a request via javascript, yes, but it's for HTML.

Comment: Gotcha. To wrap this up, I have tested with .js and the script being added as dataType. Both work (even with the "bad" routes in the respond_to block) however with the route in the respond_to block fixed i don't need either. I see whats happeneing now thanks to the both of you, and not updating my respond_to block, i have a better understanding of js and rails as a whole. There were 3 solutions to this problem which should help anyone coming in from google ;) THANKS AGAIN

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 $.ajax 
      url: "tasks/" + task_id
      dataType: "script"
      data: "&task[is_completed]=2"
      type: "PUT"
      success: ->
        $(this).addClass "done"
```

I don't think it's rendering your JS response and it's trying to use the HTML redirect (which also has problems as noted by numbers)